# How to show the Menu "Source" in RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

It's an RCP-application. I opened my own file in the Perspective "Resource" and i want to format the the text-content via "Source->Format". How to make the Menu "Source" visible?

Comment: Format what? Java? Something else? is this an e4 or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP? Are you using your own ActionBarAdvisor?

Comment: to format the Text-Context of a file with my own File-Extention. The mode is 3.x compability. I'm not using my own ActionBarAdvisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Source menu is added by the Eclipse JDT plugin and has id `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source.menu`.

You will normally define your own Source menu using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.

Something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
     <menu
           id="id.source.menu"
           label="Source">
        <command
              commandId="id.source.format"
              label="Format"
              style="push">
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
```

Comment: That helps. I can show now the Sub menu Format. It's Possible to give me some details about to call the methode [IContentFormatter getContentFormatter(ISourceViewer sourceViewer] from my configuration class that extends SourceViewerConfiguration?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html)